# C# cast a class to an Interface List

Tags: c#, interface, casting, invoke

I'm trying to load some .dll files dynamically. The Files are Plugins (self-written for now) which have at least one class that implements `MyInterface`. For each file I'm doing the following:

```
    Dictionary<MyInterface, bool> _myList;

    // ...code

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(currentFile.FullName);
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        var myI = type.GetInterface("MyInterface");
        if(myI != null)
        {
            if ((myI.Name == "MyInterface") && !type.IsAbstract)
            {
                var p = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                _myList.Add((MyInterface)p, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Running this causes a cast exception, but I can't find a workaround. Anyway I am wondering why this doesn't work at all. I'm looking for a solution in .NET Framework 3.5.

Another thing that happened to me was getting `null` in `p` after running the following at the point before adding a new entry to `_myList` in the code above:

```
var p = type.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null,
                          null, null) as MyInterface;
```

This code was the first attempt on loading the plugins, I didn't find out why `p` was `null` yet.
I hope someone can lead me to the right way :)

Comment: this code is not working, what is x and where you init it?

Comment: In your code snippet above, is "x" in "if (x !=null)" really supposed to be "myI"?

Comment: You should also verify that the type has a default constructor, since your code assumes that.

Comment: I don't understand `var myI = type.GetInterface("MyInterface");  if(x != null)`.  Should it be `if (myI != null)`?

Comment: [Activator.CreateInsance(type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx) assumes there is a parameterless constructor of your type. What kind of exception do you get? If it's `MissingMethodException` the problem (almost for sure) is that your class does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I renamed x sorry for that I edited it. Yes my "Plugin" has a parameterless constructor and I'll check that too if it's working so far. I get a `InvalidCastException`

Comment: @Z3R0 Is it possible the `InvalidCastException` comes from the type's constructor?

Comment: the type's constructor is `MyPlugin(){}`
and the stack trace says it's on the `_myList.Add(...);` line.
btw it says "PluginTest.MyPlugin cannot be PluginSystem.MyInterface"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really read [Plug-ins and cast exceptions](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/plugin.html) by Jon Skeet which explains the behaviour you see and how to do plug-in frameworks properly.

Comment: What I could take out of it was that the plugin's assembly is not the same as my application's assembly.

Comment: I wish more people would vote this one up, as I think that's probably the OP's issue.  Basically, if you think of this like C++, and the Interface definition like a .h file, you'll run into this error.  If you think of it in a "managed types" way you'll see that there's two interfaces, one per file, if it's being compiled the (wrong) way the link says it might be.

Answer (score 5):

There's much easier way to check if your type can be casted to your interface.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(currentFile.FullName);
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if(!typeof(MyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        continue;

    var p = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    _myList.Add((MyInterface)p, true);
}
```

If `IsAssignableFrom` is false, there's something wrong with your inheritance, which is most likely cause of your errors.

Comment: well yes it's `false`. However I have only one member now and really don't know what could be wrong with the inheritance.

Comment: Does your "plugin" assembly reference the assembly where interface is defined? Does your running code (code in sample) reference *same* assembly?

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the following code. I think [Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can help you out in this situation.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(currentFile.FullName);
///Get all the types defined in selected  file
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

///check if we have a compatible type defined in chosen  file?
Type compatibleType = types.SingleOrDefault(x => typeof(MyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x));

if (compatibleType != null)
{
    ///if the compatible type exists then we can proceed and create an instance of a platform
    found = true;
    //create an instance here
    MyInterface obj = (ALPlatform)AreateInstance(compatibleType);

}
```